# differences between make_unique and make_shared when handling arrays

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, make-shared

as of C++17 you can use `make_unique` in order to create smart pointers to arrays, such as:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = make_unique<int[]>(10);
```

which will create a smart pointer to an array of 10 elements (the fact that proper deleter[] will be called is also great).

However according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) `make_shared` does not support such functionality (at least not in C++17, to my understanding):

```
shared_ptr<int[]> ptr = make_shared<int[]>(10);
```

the code above is apparently illegal. Indeed, my Visual Studio 2017 (v141) spits out the following error:

```
C2070: 'int[]': illegal sizeof operand'
```

What's interesting is that `shared_ptr` itself does support array types (i.e., `shared_ptr<int[]>` is [legal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)), but `make_shared` does not. Whereas `make_unique` does.

The question is, what prevented the standard maker people to let `make_shared` support array types, just like in the case of `make_unique`?

Comment: `std::make_shared` supports arrays from C++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared  Why not earlier, I suppose because someone has to write the proposal, advocate for it, get 1 or more implementations written etc.  They probably had something else scheduled.

Comment: It was an oversight/deficiency in the c++14 and c++17 standards. It's in c++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What prevented the standard maker people to let make_shared support array types [...]?

Probably nothing, this case was simply not considered, similar to `std::make_unique` not being present in C++11 but added in C++14. And as pointed out in the comments, this missing piece will ship with C++20.

There is a difference between `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` that made neglecting raw arrays pointers easy, though: custom deleters are part of `std::unique_ptr`'s type but not part of `std::shared_ptr`'s type. Therefore, you can handle an array like this

```
std::shared_ptr<int> array = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[10],
    [](int *ptr){ delete []ptr; });
```

and hence delegate the correct memory cleanup to the point of object creation. This makes it easy to treat raw arrays as a special case of `std::shared_ptr` instances.

Comment: It appears, however, that as of C++17 `shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[10])`  similarly invokes delete[] (see the link in the original question). Also, I did not encounter any memory leaks when declaring a shared pointer in such fashion.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Seems that this is something libstdc++ provides, independent of the language standard (tested with `gcc-8` for `-std=c++11/14/17`), but not libc++ (tested with `clang-6`?!

Comment: @lubgr IIRC and everything I see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) shows me that `shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[10])` should work fine in C++17.  Pre C++17 you could also use `std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[1]); std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(std::move(arr));`

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right, I think I screwed up the flags for using the homebrew-up-to-date standard headers when testing. Should work with clang, too.